# Cypress add "undefined" word before url when i use Cy.visit

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation

when I wrote

```
cy.visit('https://www.google.com');
```

in runner I see this :[Cypress Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thNSO.png)

Could anyone how to remove this undefined

I tried to call it several ways like  base url or environment but I see same result everytime

Comment: What version of Cypress are you using? Can you share your Cypress configuration?

Comment: 11.2 and this was in an older version but the upgradation didn't resolve it

and my configuration file here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1apoatdoF60G87vTP1xhDntiS5wvCuvbW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please do not link out to external files. Instead, copy the code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have baseUrl defined in your configuration.

Comment: defined and  even with a value still had the same response

Comment: Are you trying to visit other domain than your application?